# Code for a stacked histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to create histograms of diamond price which show the proportion of diamonds by cut. This is as far as I got:

```
ggplot(aes(x = price), data = diamonds_df) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, fill = "white", colour = "black") +
facet_wrap(~color, scales = "free_y") + 
scale_x_log10() +
ylab("Total Count") +
xlab("Diamond Price") +
ggtitle("Distribution of diamond prices for different diamond colours and cuts")
```

I have tried using

```
color = cut
```

and also

```
fill = cut
```

within the aesthetic wrapper but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This code gives the plot I want but it looks quite messy.

```
ggplot(diamonds_df, aes(price, fill=cut)) + 
geom_bar(width = 0.05) +
facet_wrap(~color, scales = "free_y") + 
scale_x_log10() +
ylab("Total Count") +
xlab("Diamond Price") +
ggtitle("Distribution of diamond prices for different diamond colours and cuts")
```

Comment: Use `geom_histogram` and specify a larger `binwidth`?